# I need to get the data stored to my sqlite data.db file and displayed in the table

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, android-sqlite

I got this code from Youtube, it's very useful, but the data is being stored in a websql database, and I would like it to be stored instead in a database file called data.db located in my data folder. How could I do that process using javascript, or node. Not other technologies.

I would like you to help me to store the data in my sqlite database, I attach an image of my structure in case it is needed. I can only use html, css, js and sqlite in my project.
[Structure of my project, (sql.js file is not being used)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwtq5.png)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/r.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <script src="banco.js"></script>
        <script src="sqlite3.js"></script>
        <title>SQLite: Insert, Select & Update</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>SQLite: Insert, Select & Update</h1>
        <div class="aligncenter">
            <form class="form">
                <input type="hidden" id="field-id" value="" />
                <div class="box">
                    <input type="text" id="field-name"/>
                    <label for="field-name">Nome</label>
                </div>

                <div class="box">
                    <input type="text" id="field-pass"/>
                    <label for="field-pass">Senha</label>
                </div>

                <div class="box">
                    <input type="text" id="field-mail"/>
                    <label for="field-mail">E-mail</label>
                </div>
                <div class="per"><a id="btn-salvar" class="button" >SALVAR</a></div>
                <div class="per"><a id="btn-deletar" class="button" >DELETAR</a></div>
            </form>
            <table id="table-register">
                <thead>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Senha</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody-register">
                
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

#JS with the functions

```
window.addEventListener('load', carregado);

var db = openDatabase("myDB", "1.0", "TiPS Database Example", 2 * 1024 * 1024);



function carregado(){    
    
    document.getElementById('btn-salvar').addEventListener('click', salvar);
    document.getElementById('btn-deletar').addEventListener('click', deletar);
    
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        //tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE myTable" );
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,nome TEXT,senha TEXT, email TEXT)" );
//        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO myTable ( nome,senha,email) VALUES ("a", "b", "c")');
    });
    
    mostrar();
    
}   

function salvar(){
    var id = document.getElementById('field-id').value;
    var nome = document.getElementById('field-name').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('field-pass').value;
    var mail = document.getElementById('field-mail').value;

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        if(id){
            tx.executeSql('UPDATE myTable SET nome=?, senha=?, email=? WHERE id=?', [nome,pass,mail,id],null);
        }else{
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO myTable ( nome,senha,email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [nome,pass,mail]);
        }
    });

    mostrar();
    limpaCampo();
    inputSHOW(false);
}

function mostrar(){        
    var table = document.getElementById('tbody-register');

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM myTable', [], function (tx, resultado) {
            var rows = resultado.rows;
            var tr = '';
            for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                    tr += '<tr>';
                    tr += '<td onClick="atualizar(' + rows[i].id + ')">' + rows[i].nome + '</td>';
                    tr += '<td>' + rows[i].senha + '</td>';
                    tr += '<td>' + rows[i].email + '</td>';
                    tr += '</tr>';                   
            }
                table.innerHTML = tr; 

        }, null);
    });
}

function atualizar(_id){   
    
    var id = document.getElementById('field-id');
    var nome = document.getElementById('field-name');
    var pass = document.getElementById('field-pass');
    var mail = document.getElementById('field-mail');
    
    id.value = _id;
    
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=?', [_id], function (tx, resultado) {
            var rows = resultado.rows[0];

            nome.value = rows.nome ;
            pass.value = rows.senha ;
            mail.value = rows.email ;
        });
    });
    inputSHOW(true);
}

function deletar(){
    
    var id = document.getElementById('field-id').value;
    
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id=?", [id]);
    });
    
    mostrar();
    limpaCampo();
    inputSHOW(false);
}
```

This code is not important. But I always attach it
JS

```
window.addEventListener('load',carrega);

function carrega(){
    document.getElementById('field-name').addEventListener('blur', leave);
    document.getElementById('field-pass').addEventListener('blur', leave);
    document.getElementById('field-mail').addEventListener('blur', leave);   
}
function leave(){
    if(this.value != ''){
        this.offsetParent.className += " ativo";
    }else{
        this.offsetParent.className = 'box';
    }
}

function inputSHOW(_show){
    if(_show){
        document.getElementById('field-name').offsetParent.className += " ativo";
        document.getElementById('field-pass').offsetParent.className += " ativo";
        document.getElementById('field-mail').offsetParent.className += " ativo";
        document.getElementById('btn-deletar').style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        
        document.getElementById('field-name').offsetParent.className = 'box';
        document.getElementById('field-pass').offsetParent.className = 'box';
        document.getElementById('field-mail').offsetParent.className = 'box';
        //document.getElementById('btn-deletar').style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function limpaCampo(){
    
    document.getElementById('field-id').value = '';
    document.getElementById('field-name').value = '';
    document.getElementById('field-pass').value = '';
    document.getElementById('field-mail').value = '';
}
```